# Cloning a website via wget

Tags: clone-site

Is it possible to somehow upload files downloaded via “wget -r” onto a server to replicate the actual website, If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, a WGET can be used to download a site's page(s) to your local machine. Then, you could theoretically upload those files to your own web server, and the results will look like the original site. But only as the site existed when you WGET'd the individual pages.

WordPress stores all site content in a database, and then 'builds' the page using templates and other processes to display the actual content. If the content changes in the database, then your WGET'd files will not be the same as the actual site.

And then there is the whole issue of copyright infringement, and content ownership, which is not something you mentioned.

So, although technically possible to 'snapshot' a site (the "Wayback Mahine" does that, for instance), it will not be a 'true' clone of the site.